# Word's Footlight MT Light font in LaTeX

Tags: fonts

What's the LaTeX font most near Word's Footlight MT Light font? Word's font Footlight MT Light can be viewed here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/footlight-mt

Comment: you can use exactly the same font with lualatex

Comment: I just compile the file in LuaLaTeX and the result is not Footlight MT Light fonts in text... ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You don’t show any code, so we cannot help you in an efficient way. If you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you can load fonts installed on your system using the `fontspec` package. With PDFLaTeX, you need indeed to use a compatible font, maybe you can find one at https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lualatex (or xelatex) can use the same system-installed fonts as other applications:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Footlight MT Light}
\begin{document}

Hello World.

\end{document}
```

The font only has one style but if needed you can tell `fontspec`to use the same font but with faked features, mechanically making bold and slant

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
BoldFont={Footlight MT Light},
ItalicFont={Footlight MT Light},
BoldItalicFont={Footlight MT Light},
BoldFeatures={FakeBold=2},
ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.5},
BoldItalicFeatures={FakeBold=2,FakeSlant=0.5}
]
{Footlight MT Light}
\begin{document}

Hello World.

\textit{Hello World.}

\textbf{Hello World.}

\textit{\textbf{Hello World.}}


\end{document}
```

Comment: That's it! And how I can use bolds and italics? The commands ```\textbf``` and ```\textit``` seem not work.

Comment: @Carl see update with bold italic

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Slanted just a tiny touch too much for my taste ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht yes and bold too bold, but it's easier to test with exagerated values